# Convert a file of strings to required format : replace / with _ except the ones before comma

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to covert a file in particular format.

Here is the example:

```
>>> x = "abc/xyz/abc/xyz/ab_c : abc/xyz/abc/xyz/ab_c,ab_c/xy_z/ab_c/xy_z/ab_c/xy_z,1"
```

I need to replace all the `/` with `_` except the ones which are before `,` and a space after `,`.

Output needed:

```
>>> 'abc_xyz_abc_xyz_ab_c : abc_xyz_abc_xyz/ab_c, ab_c_xy_z_ab_c_xy_z_ab_c/xy_z, 1'
```

I tried replacing `/` with `_` but in this case, I have no way to exclude `/` before `,`.

```
>>> x.replace("/", "_").replace(",", ", ")
'abc_xyz_abc_xyz_ab_c : abc_xyz_abc_xyz_ab_c, ab_c_xy_z_ab_c_xy_z_ab_c_xy_z, 1'
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into regular expressions; they'll handle this nicely.

Comment: To clarify; what if the string was `"foo/bar/baz,qux/quz"`? Should the output be `"foo_bar/baz, qux/quz"` or `"foo_bar/baz, qux_quz"`?

Comment: If string is `foo/bar/baz,qux/quz`, output should be `foo_bar/baz, qux/quz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) your splitted (at `'/'` ) text with itself shifted by 1 and put it back together using the correct in-betweens:

```
x = "abc/xyz/abc/xyz/ab_c : abc/xyz/abc/xyz/ab_c,ab_c/xy_z/ab_c/xy_z/ab_c/xy_z,1"

parts = x.split("/")
pp = zip(parts,parts[1:])

l = []
for at,after in pp:
    if ',' in after:
        l.extend([at,'/'])
    else:
        l.extend([at,'_'])
l.append(after)  

# join and add spaces after ,
new_t = ''.join(l).replace(",",", ")
print(new_t) 
print('abc_xyz_abc_xyz_ab_c : abc_xyz_abc_xyz/ab_c, ab_c_xy_z_ab_c_xy_z_ab_c/xy_z, 1')
```

Output:

```
abc_xyz_abc_xyz_ab_c : abc_xyz_abc_xyz/ab_c, ab_c_xy_z_ab_c_xy_z_ab_c/xy_z, 1
abc_xyz_abc_xyz_ab_c : abc_xyz_abc_xyz/ab_c, ab_c_xy_z_ab_c_xy_z_ab_c/xy_z, 1
```

---

The zipped thing looks like this:

```
# pp splitted zipped with itself, shifted by 1
[('abc', 'xyz'), ('xyz', 'abc'), ('abc', 'xyz'), ('xyz', 'ab_c : abc'), 
 ('ab_c : abc', 'xyz'), ('xyz', 'abc'), ('abc', 'xyz'), ('xyz', 'ab_c,ab_c'),
 ('ab_c,ab_c', 'xy_z'), ('xy_z', 'ab_c'), ('ab_c', 'xy_z'), ('xy_z', 'ab_c'),
 ('ab_c', 'xy_z,1')]
```

This code uses python 3 style printing - but it works as well in python 2